# How do I trim a pipeline object in Powershell and use it further down the pipe?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some GUIDS from the registry, trim the blank lines, then run each GUID through an uninstall, but I'm not sure how to trim each GUID before running that uninstall command.  This is what I have so far, which is not working:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Where-Object -Property DisplayName -Match MDX | Format-Table -Property PSChildName -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim() | ForEach-Object {Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/x $_ /qn /norestart" -Wait})
```

Comment: [1] get rid of the `Format-Table` & the `Out-String`. you are destroying your objects and only have formatting code from the F-T. then the O-S adds things like cr/lf and other side effects from trying to "string-ify" the butchered remnants of your objects. use `Select-Object` instead. [2] your final `ForEach-Object` can have multiple lines of code ... so have it remove blanks and trim whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get-package *mdx* | uninstall-package -whatif
```

or

```
get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
  where displayname -match mdx | select -expand pschildname | 
  foreach { start msiexec -arg "/x $_ /qn /norestart" -wait }
```

Btw, I happen to know that if you install Netbeans, it breaks listing the 64-bit Uninstall registry key properties.